# Do I need to release memory used by arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management

Suppose I have an array of objects of type class `InvoiceItem` defined below:

```
 private class InvoiceItem
    {
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public byte ItemType { get; set; }
        public short Quantity { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount{ get; set; }

        public InvoiceItem(DateTime InvoiceDate,int InvoiceID, short Quantity, string ProductName, decimal Price,decimal Amount, byte ItemType)
        {
            this.InvoiceDate = InvoiceDate;
            this.InvoiceID = InvoiceID;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
            this.ProductName = ProductName;
            this.Price = Price;
            this.Amount = Amount;
            this.ItemType = ItemType;
        }
    }
```

and I try to cache my items in an array named `invoiceItemsCache`

```
private InvoiceItem[] invoiceItemsCache;
```

every time I want to refresh my cache I reinitialize my array:

```
invoiceItemsCache = new InvoiceItem[count];
```

Do I need to do *Something* to *release* the memory used by previous cache, or is it done automatically ?  I will appreciate if anybody gives some additional information about the way arrays are stored and released in C# so to remove any doubt and confusion I encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC in C# is going through the objects and checks for references. if an object has no reference to it, then the GC release it.

in your case, if you do

```
invoiceItemsCache = new InvoiceItem[count];
```

then the old values has no reference to them (unless you have different reference to them that you did not mention and then you should dispose them first) and will be freed

Comment: Maybe he should 'dispose of some references' but certainly not `Dispose()` them. Tricky choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

It is done automatically by the underlying garbage collector.

Arrays are stored and released like any other object in C#.